# why he may have taken the documents

Tags: grammar

I am reading an Economist news report about the recent FBI raid on Trump's mansions in Florida and one sentence appears to catch me out:

> The most explosive detail is the three statutes under which the
> warrant was granted. One was against "gathering, transmitting or
> losing defence information". That law is part of the Espionage Act.
> Why Mr Trump **may have taken the documents**, and whether charges will
> follow, is unknown.

I am wondering why "may have taken" is used here. Since the documents were already in Trump's home when the FBI raided it, "may have taken" sound still like it is not 100% sure that Trump took the documents.

Does the author try not to write with absolute certainty? Or is s/he suggesting that it was someone else who took the documents (say Trump's family members, though I don't think it's convincing)?

Answer (score 2):

No, the author simply conveys his *wondering* about ***what could possibly have made him take documents***, what he *could have had* in mind when he did that.

*May* is used with perfect infinitive to express uncertainty, but the uncertainty concerns the reason why he took the documents, not the fact that he took them.

Comment: We don't know that Trump took them, only that they were found in his house. Hence "may have" also includes *that* uncertainty.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, we actually **do** know. [_In a statement earlier Friday, Mr Trump claimed that the documents seized by agents were “all declassified”, and said **he would have turned them over** if the justice department had asked._](https://www.yourlocalguardian.co.uk/news/national/20630392.fbi-seized-top-secret-documents-trumps-home/).

Comment: That still doesn't mean, or say, that he took them, only that he would have returned them if asked. Someone else may have taken them and placed them in the house. In fact, he *wouldn't* have personally loaded them into a car and carried them into the house, would he?

Answer (score 0):

Because it hadn't been established that he "took" them but only that he "may have taken" them.

Something being found in someone's home falls short of establishing that that homeowner "took" it, which would be jumping to a conclusion. If my stuffed bear is found in your home, is that in and of itself proof that you "took" it? No, it's at most circumstantial evidence that you "may have taken" it. So, if I publish that you "took" my stuffed bear without proof you really did, instead of publishing that you merely "may have taken" my stuff bear, which is all I have evidence of, then that exposes me to legal liability, to having to pay you potentially huge financial damages if and when you sue me for libel and defamation. Moreover, my using "may have taken" would not be at all suggestive that anyone else "took" my stuffed bear either because there are many, many ways my stuffed bear may have ended up in your home other than you "took" it or someone else "took" it.

By the way, this is an apolitical response. Do not mistake this as my defending Donald Trump. I'm simply explaining why a journalist and a periodical would properly report "may have taken" instead of improperly report "took" when reporting "took" with what that journalist and periodical had available to them at the time of publication would've been unfounded. Maybe "Trump took" later ends up getting proven, but until then, in order to protect their journalistic integrity and shield themselves from legal liability, it remains prudent for that journalist and that periodical to not report anything that they don't actually have proof of to back them up, and the absolute most they had proof of to back them up when publishing that was "Trump *may have taken* the documents," not "Trump *took* the documents."